# How to control multiple SPI's

Tags: arduino, spi, samd21

I am having a weeny trouble with my SAMD21 board. I have got this starter kit (schematics) and I want to add some more sensors. They use SPI, so I programmed them. Since SAMD21 got the code it lag's everytime, when code reache's the sensor begin function. Please give me some advice, how to control both SPI's correctly and avoid lags.

*lags are total lags - SAMD21 do nothing after reaching the begin function.

*schematics: http://kit.sciencein.cz/wiki/images/b/be/MainBoard_v2.0_RevB_SCH.png

*sorry for mistakes in the code (it is long code cut to short)

*my code:

```
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>  // include Adafruit BME280 library
  #include <Adafruit_INA219.h>  // include INA219
  #include <SD.h>          // include Arduino SD library
  #include "Open_Cansat_GPS.h"

  //include our new sensors
  #include "MQ131.h"

  #include <Wire.h>
  #include <SPI.h>

  #include "RFM69.h"       // include RFM69 library

  // Local
  #define PC_BAUDRATE       115200
  #define MS_DELAY    0  // Number of milliseconds between data sending and LED signalization
  #define LED_DELAY     100
  #define Serial SerialUSB
  RTCZero rtc;

  // RFM69
  #define NETWORKID       0        // Must be the same for all nodes (0 to 255)
  #define MYNODEID        1          // My node ID (0 to 255)
  #define TONODEID        2          // Destination node ID (0 to 254, 255 = broadcast)
  #define FREQUENCY       RF69_433MHZ   // Frequency set up
  #define FREQUENCYSPECIFIC 433000000  // Should be value in Hz, now 433 Mhz will be set
  #define CHIP_SELECT_PIN   43 //radio chip select
  #define INTERUP_PIN       9 //radio interrupt

  // BME280 SETTING
  #define BME280_ADDRESS_OPEN_CANSAT 0x77
  #define SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA    1013.25

  //OZONE2CLICK
  const byte pinSS = 2; //cs pin
  const byte pinRDY = 12;
  const byte pinSCK = 13;
  const byte O2Pin = 10;
  #define DcPin 8

  // SD card
  #define sd_cs_pin 35 // set SD's chip select pin (according to the circuit)

  // create object 'rf69' from the library, which will
  // be used to access the library methods by a dot notation
  RFM69 radio(CHIP_SELECT_PIN, INTERUP_PIN, true);

  // define our own struct data type with variables; used to send data
  typedef struct
  {
    int16_t messageId;
    uint16_t year;
    uint8_t month;
    uint8_t day;
    uint8_t hour;
    uint8_t minute;
    uint8_t sec;
    float longitude;
    float latitude;
    uint8_t num_of_satelites;
    float temperature;
    float pressure;
    float altitude;
    float humidity_bme280;
    float voltage_shunt;
    float voltage_bus;
    float current_mA;
    float voltage_load;
    int16_t rssi;
  } messageOut;

  messageOut cansatdata; //create the struct variable

  // create object 'bme' from the library, which will
  // be used to access the library methods by a dot notation
  Adafruit_BME280 bme;

  // create object 'ina219' from the library with address 0x40
  // (according to the circuit, which will be used to access the
  // library methods by a dot notation
  Adafruit_INA219 ina219(0x40);

  // create object 'gps' from the library
  OpenCansatGPS gps;

  // SD card 
  File file; // SD library variable

  // LEDS
  #define D13_led_pin 42  // D13 LED
  #define M_led_pin 36  // MLED

  // Local variables
  int idCounter = 1;
  bool isBmeOk = true;
  bool isSdOk = true;
  bool isRadioOk = true;
  bool isGpsConnected = true;

  // My variables
  float NH3Data;
  float COData;
  float NO2Data;
  float PPMO2;
  float PPBO2;
  float MGM3O2;
  float UGM3O2;
  float SSmoke1;
  float SSmoke2;
  float SSmoke3; 
  float ESmoke1;
  float ESmoke2;
  float ESmoke3;
  int DataCounter = 0;


  void OZONE2CLICKCalibrate ()
  {
  Serial.println("2");
    //MQ131.begin(pinSS, pinRDY, O2Pin, LOW_CONCENTRATION, 10000);  //(int _pinCS, int _pinRDY, int _pinPower, MQ131Model _model, int _RL)
    Serial.println("99");
    Serial.println("Calibration in progress...");

    MQ131.calibrate();

    Serial.println("Calibration done!");
    Serial.print("R0 = ");
    Serial.print(MQ131.getR0());
    Serial.println(" Ohms");
    Serial.print("Time to heat = ");
    Serial.print(MQ131.getTimeToRead());
    Serial.println(" s");
    }

  void OZONE2CLICKMeasure ()
  {
    Serial.println("Sampling...");
    MQ131.sample();
    Serial.print("Concentration O3 : ");
    PPMO2 = MQ131.getO3(PPM);
    Serial.print(PPMO2);
    Serial.println(" ppm");
    Serial.print("Concentration O3 : ");
    PPBO2 = MQ131.getO3(PPB);
    Serial.print(PPBO2);
    Serial.println(" ppb");
    Serial.print("Concentration O3 : ");
    MGM3O2 = MQ131.getO3(MG_M3);
    Serial.print(MGM3O2);
    Serial.println(" mg/m3");
    Serial.print("Concentration O3 : ");
    UGM3O2 = MQ131.getO3(UG_M3);
    Serial.print(UGM3O2);
    Serial.println(" ug/m3");
  }



  void setup()
  {
    pinMode(pinSS, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(pinSS, HIGH);
    delay(10000);
    Serial.begin(PC_BAUDRATE);

    // wait for the Arduino serial (on your PC) to connect
    // please, open the Arduino serial console (right top corner)
    // note that the port may change after uploading the sketch
    // COMMENT OUT FOR USAGE WITHOUT A PC!
    // while(!Serial);

    Serial.println("openCanSat PRO");

    Serial.print("Node ");
    Serial.print(MYNODEID,DEC);
    Serial.println(" ready");

    // begin communication with the BME280 on the previously specified address
    // print an error to the serial in case the sensor is not found
    if (!bme.begin(BME280_ADDRESS_OPEN_CANSAT))
    {
      isBmeOk = false;
      Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor, check wiring!");
      return;
    }

    // begin communication with the INA219
    ina219.begin();

    // check of Gps is connected
    Wire.beginTransmission(0x42); // 42 is addres of GPS
    int error = Wire.endTransmission();

    if (error != 0)
    {
      isGpsConnected = false;
    }

    // begin communication with gps
    gps.begin();

    // Uncomment when you want to see debug prints from GPS library
    // gps.debugPrintOn(57600);

    if(!radio.initialize(FREQUENCY, MYNODEID, NETWORKID))
    {
      isRadioOk = false;
      Serial.println("RFM69HW initialization failed!");
    }
    else
    {
      radio.setFrequency(FREQUENCYSPECIFIC);
      radio.setHighPower(true); // Always use this for RFM69HW
    }

    pinMode(D13_led_pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(DcPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MICS6814Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MICSVZ89TEPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(O2Pin, OUTPUT);
    GyroscopeTurnOn();
  }

  void loop()
  {
    cansatdata.messageId = idCounter;
    GyroscopeMeasure();
    LandingChecker();    

    Serial.println("MessageId = " + static_cast<String>(cansatdata.messageId));

    cansatdata.temperature = 0;
    cansatdata.pressure = 0;
    cansatdata.altitude = 0;

    if(isBmeOk)
    {
      cansatdata.temperature += bme.readTemperature();
      cansatdata.pressure += bme.readPressure() / 100.0F;
      cansatdata.altitude += bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA);
      cansatdata.humidity_bme280 = bme.readHumidity();
    }

    Serial.println("Temperature = " + static_cast<String>(cansatdata.temperature) + " *C");
    Serial.println("Pressure = " + static_cast<String>(cansatdata.pressure) + " Pa");
    Serial.println("Approx altitude = " + static_cast<String>(cansatdata.altitude) + " m");
    Serial.println("Humidity = " + static_cast<String>(cansatdata.humidity_bme280) + " %");

    // read values from INA219 into structure
    cansatdata.voltage_shunt = ina219.getShuntVoltage_mV();
    cansatdata.voltage_bus = ina219.getBusVoltage_V();
    cansatdata.current_mA = ina219.getCurrent_mA();
    cansatdata.voltage_load = cansatdata.voltage_bus + (cansatdata.voltage_shunt / 1000);

    Serial.println("Shunt Voltage: " + static_cast<String>(cansatdata.voltage_shunt) + " mV");
    Serial.println("Bus Voltage: " + static_cast<String>(cansatdata.voltage_bus) + " V");
    Serial.println("Current: " + static_cast<String>(cansatdata.current_mA) + " mA");
    Serial.println("Load Voltage: " + static_cast<String>(cansatdata.voltage_load) + " V");

    // Initialize GPS
    cansatdata.year = 0;
    cansatdata.month = 0  ;
    cansatdata.day = 0;
    cansatdata.hour = 0;
    cansatdata.minute = 0;
    cansatdata.sec = 0;
    cansatdata.latitude = 0;
    cansatdata.longitude = 0;
    cansatdata.num_of_satelites = 0;

    // save start time in millisec
    uint32_t start = millis();

    // END LED BLINK
    digitalWrite(D13_led_pin, LOW);


    pinMode(M_led_pin, INPUT);
    // END LED BLINK

    if(isGpsConnected)
    {
      if (gps.scan(250))
      {
        cansatdata.year = gps.getYear();
        cansatdata.month = gps.getMonth();
        cansatdata.day = gps.getDay();
        cansatdata.hour = gps.getHour();
        cansatdata.minute = gps.getMinute();
        cansatdata.sec = gps.getSecond();
        cansatdata.latitude = gps.getLat();
        cansatdata.longitude = gps.getLon();
        cansatdata.num_of_satelites = gps.getNumberOfSatellites();
        Serial.println(String("Time to find fix: ") + (millis() - start) + String("ms"));
        Serial.println(String("Datetime: ") + String(cansatdata.year) + "/"+ String(cansatdata.month) + "/"+ String(cansatdata.day) + " " + String(cansatdata.hour) + ":"+ String(cansatdata.minute) + ":"+ String(cansatdata.sec));
        Serial.println(String("Lat: ") + String(cansatdata.latitude, 7));
        Serial.println(String("Lon: ") + String(cansatdata.longitude, 7));
        Serial.println(String("Num of sats: ") + String(cansatdata.num_of_satelites));
        Serial.println();
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println("Gps have no satelit to fix.");
      }
    }

    // RFM69HW
    cansatdata.rssi = 0;

    if(isRadioOk)
    {
      cansatdata.rssi = radio.RSSI;
      Serial.println("Signal = " + static_cast<String>(radio.RSSI));

      radio.send(TONODEID, (const void*)&cansatdata, sizeof(cansatdata));
    }

    Serial.println();

    // START LED hart beat
    pinMode(M_led_pin, OUTPUT);

    digitalWrite(D13_led_pin, HIGH);

    digitalWrite(M_led_pin, HIGH);
    // START LED hart beat

    if(!isGpsConnected)
    {
    delay(200);
    }

    idCounter ++;

  }
```

Comment: Maybe you need to elaborate whaat is the meaning of " it lag's everytime, when code reache's the sensor begin function". What is lagging? and there is no where in your code calling a begin() function for SPI devices(there are several for i2c devices) in your code. The schematic shows there are 2 SPI devices, the SD card and the 433MHz radio, however, there is no where in your code using the SD card other than initialises a SS pin for SD card.

Comment: set CS pin of the second device HIGH before initializing the first device

Comment: The SAMD21 will lag and is lagged - I do not know, what to say, simply is lagged and I need to restart it.